# python aggregate columns from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two data frames:

`df1`

```
       A  B  C  D
Index
1      0  1  1  3
2      1  0  3  1
3      4  0  1  1
4      0  2  2  2
```

`df2`

```
       A  B
Index
1      1  2
2      3  4
3      0  0
4      1  2
```

I want my output to be

`df_result`

```
       A  B  C  D
Index
1      1  3  1  3
2      4  4  3  1
3      4  0  1  1
4      1  4  2  2
```

Basically, I want to aggregate the similar columns values, and also include non-similar columns to the result. Note that the `df1` and `df2` will always have same index.

How can I do this in python's pandas library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by columns and aggregate `sum`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
print (df)
       A  B  C  D
Index            
1      1  3  1  3
2      4  4  3  1
3      4  0  1  1
4      1  4  2  2
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).sum(axis=1, level=0)
print (df)
       A  B  C  D
Index            
1      1  3  1  3
2      4  4  3  1
3      4  0  1  1
4      1  4  2  2
```

Comment: That was really really fast

Comment: I have a feeling that you start typing an answer before the question is posted ;-)

Comment: Even I felt the same

Comment: I had a dinner a few minutes ago, so maybe it help me ;)

Comment: Gosh, thank you. I guess it's my lucky day :D. going to accept answer in 4 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `add` with `fill_value`

```
In [4336]: df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
Out[4336]:
       A  B    C    D
Index
1      1  3  1.0  3.0
2      4  4  3.0  1.0
3      4  0  1.0  1.0
4      1  4  2.0  2.0
```

---

Or, use `reindex`

```
In [4341]: df1 + df2.reindex(columns=df1.columns, fill_value=0)
Out[4341]:
       A  B  C  D
Index
1      1  3  1  3
2      4  4  3  1
3      4  0  1  1
4      1  4  2  2
```